# Usage of "now" and "then" referring to people

Tags: word-choice, time-words

> It was Mr. JACOB then, and now it is Mr NASIR who has done the same mistake

Is this sentence correct? Referring to a previous case it was Mr. Jacob and now it is Mr. Nasir?

Comment: The time-words are used correctly; but we say "*made* the same mistake".

Comment: When I saw the title I expected a question about constructions like “Mr N, then mayor of Zabranchburg, now ambassador to Ruritania”.

Answer (score 0):

True. 'Then' is *also* used to refer to the things happened in past.

> Truly loyal to the organization ***then***, he has now become a dissent

So, in your sentence, it says -in the past, it was Jacob. And, now it is Nasir. However, as TRomano pointed out, we use 'make' with mistake rather than 'do'.